# Using almond with grunt-contrib-requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, almond

I'm trying to set up a gruntfile that utilizes requirejs and almond. The [docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs) suggest it should be really easy, and following their lead, I tried:

```
requirejs: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: "tmp",
      mainConfigFile: "tmp/main.js",
      name: "../bower_components/almond/almond",
      out: "tmp/<%= pkg.name %>.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach compiles `almond.js` rather than my actual source. Am I getting something wrong? How do I automate almond along with requirejs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick is to use [include](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs/issues/24):

```
requirejs: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: "tmp",
      mainConfigFile: "tmp/main.js",
      include: "main",
      name: "../bower_components/almond/almond",
      out: "tmp/<%= pkg.name %>.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Where `main` is the require.js file you would typically call like so:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```